# RESTful WCF security/authentication and jQuery AJAX calls

Tags: wcf, rest, jquery, restful-authentication

I am fairly new WCF and fast discovering what a massive framework it is! It's quite overwhelming when you're trying to figure out what I thought to be a simple concept.

I am trying to create a set of services, some of which are available to public, and others should require authentication. The latter include things related to user accounts, eg. my items, my profile config, etc. I am also trying to create them as RESTful services that can be consumed by jQuery AJAX calls.

I managed to create simple RESTful services with GET methods but I can't imagine creating POST ones being much more complicated. The biggest issue now is how do I create authentication-required services? I am using webHttpBinding, and not sure if that is the best.

This is all getting a little overwhelming with just about every Google search result pointing in different directions. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction. What do I need to do this, both from the WCF service side, and making the calls from jQuery?

I'm sure I have been somewhat waffly, mainly because I'm still groping for some concepts. Please bear with me and I will expand my question as necessary.

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am about to try this solution [WCF, RESTful Web Services and custom authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021612/wcf-restful-web-services-and-custom-authentication). I'm hoping someone will jump in with other suggestions if there are better ideas.